# Six Hindu philosophical systems and Puranas

Tags: puranas, philosophy, shad-darshana

There are six philosophical systems in Hinduism: Sankhya, Yoga, Nyaya, Vaisheshika, Mimamsa and Vedanta.

What is each school's opinion on Puranas?
Do they accept the puranas as authentic or they reject or don't comment on them?

Comment: Vedanta accepts them, Mimamsa reject them or treat them as Arthavadas(meaningless statements)

Comment: Interesting, could you elaborate more on Mimamsa views on Puranas @SparkSunshine

Answer (score 2):

**Vedanta**:
*PURĀNAS* are only Accepted as Fully Authoritative by *VEDANTA* school of Thought.

*Vaishnava Vedanta Schools* are built on Purānas itself. *Vishnu* and *Bhāgavatam* are the most Important Purānas for them. For *Shaktism* it’s *Devi Bhāgavatam*. *Puranic Shaiva Vedanta Schools* accept *Shaiva Purānas* are the ultimate Supreme *Purānas*.
*Smartha Advaita Vedanta* Sect also accepts all *Purānas* as well as *Upa-Purānas.* (Modern Neo Advaita doesn’t care about Puranas though).

**Mimamsa** rejects them as meaningless.

**Nyaya, Vaisheshika and Navya Nyaya** doesn’t care about Puranas as their philosophies aren’t built up on them. They don’t view them as authoritative.

**Classical Samkhya and Yoga** too do not care about Puranas as their philosophies aren’t built up on them (though Purānas mention many philosophical discourses on Samkhya and Yoga. But note: Puranic Samkhya and Classical Samkhya of Isvara Krishna are different).

**Conclusion: Only Vedanta School of Thought accepts them as fully authoritative next to Vedas.**

Comment: Please add references to support your answer. Check this out https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Firstly, Mīmāṁsā doesn't take the Purāṇas as meaningless, check adhyāya 1, pada 3 of Mīmāṁsā sūtras along with Kumārila and Śabara's commentary, it discusses the authority of smr̥ti including Purāṇas and dharmaśāstras such as Manusmr̥ti. Also, Nyāya doesn't explicitly reject Purāṇas either, check Vātsyāyana's bhāṣya [253.16-254.8]  on Nyāya Sūtra and Vācaspati's Tātparya Ṭīkā (601.1-10) on Nyāya sūtras where both explain how Purāṇas and dharmaśāstras are valid sources of knowledge.

Comment: Yeah but think from a rational perspective. Purānas don’t support Nyaya but Vedanta. Vācaspati's Comments are invalid since he was actually a Vedantin. It’s obvious he’d accept Purānas and smritis. Moreover both Vātsyāyana's and Vācaspati's comments on “accepting” the Puranas as valid sources of knowledge as per Nyaya are absurd since the Puranas support Vedanta Philosophy and have nothing to do with Nyaya Philosophy. If you think Purānas support Nyaya Philosophy please provide references from Purānas. I’m not talking through their commentary perspective but a rational perspective.

Comment: Purānas give detailed explanation of Vedanta, Samkhya, Yoga. However they’re all contradictory to Nyaya Vaisheshika. It is absurd for Nyaya Philosophers to accept Purānas because then they’d obviously be believing in a text which is against their philosophy. I’m sure there are historical and social reasons why they wrote this. But if you think form a rational perspective, you’d know it doesn’t make sense.

Comment: I didn't say they support always, Nyāya takes Veda as the foremost. I just said that Nyāya does assert that the Purāṇas are *proper sources of knowledge*. Also, it's clearly discussed, that the knowledge-source status varies according to topic, because the texts are organized according to topical differences.
Now you are busy saying that Vātsyāyana and others are incorrect, since you yourself reject the commentaries of most of the Naiyāyikas without reading them properly , there is no use in talking. FYI, Uddyotkara followed Vātsyāyana too in this issue. And both of these are not Vedāntins.

Comment: So, you misunderstood what I and the commentaries on Nyāya sūtra are saying, no where did the commentaries or I said that Purāṇas align with the Nyāya philosophy. The commentaries discuss the status of the Purāṇas whether they can be considered proper  sources of knowledge or not or should Veda only be considered so. Their status is being discussed rationally, and proper reasons are given. Not that nyāya uses Purāṇas in their arguments like Vedāntic schools, everyone knows that Nyāya seldom uses Purāṇas in its inferences and reasoning. So, please read properly  before being so excited. 

Comment: My point was them accepting Purānas as valid source of knowledge is nothing but a joke. Nobody would accept a text which goes against their philosophy.

Comment: That's your own personal viewpoint and doesn't depend on the traditional commentaries of Nyāya sūtra

Comment: Yeah that’s what I said before. (But what I said about Purānas and Nyaya Philosophy are indeed a fact. Purānas have nothing to do with Nyaya and are in fact against Nyaya).